# How to set up SSL protocols priority in OpenSSL

Tags: ssl, openssl

I am implementing an SSL Client using OpenSSL which 
(1) only "speaks" TLS 1.2, TLS 1.1 and TLS 1.0, 
(2) set exactly this priority: TLS 1.2. If communication is not possible, use TLS 1.1. If not, TLS 1.0. If not, refuse connection.

I achieve (1) by using

```
SSL_CTX_set_options(m_ssl_ctx, SSL_OP_NO_SSLv2 | SSL_OP_NO_SSLv3);
```

But I don't know any way to achieve (2). Is there any "elegant" way to do this in OpenSSL or do I have to attempt several connections checking if communication was possible and, if not, attempt a lower protocol version?

Thanks.

Comment: You can do this at an OpenSSL *server.* The server decides the protocol. Apache HTTPD, OpenLDAP, MySQL, of the major pieces of software I know that use OpenSSL, all manage it OK via their configuration files. It's not mandated by the RFC, but OpenSSL definitely allows it. For example this how you mitigate the BEAST attack.

Comment: @EJP: *"For example this how you mitigate the BEAST attack [at the server]..."* - the standard does *not* specify whether the client's preferred cipher suite or the server's preferred cipher suite is used. Its customary to allow the client to choose (by the server selecting the client's first choice). For the behavior you describe, you need to add [`SSL_OP_CIPHER_SERVER_PREFERENCE`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/ssl/SSL_CTX_set_options.html) flag at the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no protocol priority setting. The client will announce the best version it can do to the server and the server will pick this or a lower version. If the version picked by the server is not supported by the client then the handshake will fail. This is not specific to OpenSSL but this is how SSL/TLS works.

Don't confuse this handshake between client and server with the TLS downgrading mechanism most browsers use. In this case browsers retry the SSL handshake on a new TCP connection with a lower version if the handshake with the better version failed. This behavior is to work around broken SSL/TLS implementations. These downgrades are mostly restricted to browsers, simpler TLS stacks are less tolerant and fail permanently if the first handshake failed.

Comment: There is no "TLS min" and "TLS max" version. There's a record layer version and a protocol version. They are independent. While clients and servers most often use the record layer/protocol version that way, its not documented that way in the standard. Ergo, [TLS Fallback Signaling Cipher Suite Value (SCSV)](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/draft-bmoeller-tls-downgrade-scsv/). Open question: If everyone is using it that way, then why does the IETF not document it and standardize it instead of giving use yet another option (which downlevel servers won't implement anyway).

Comment: From my understanding the fallback signaling is only to tell the server, that the previous attempt of the client with a better TLS version did not work, in the assumption that this is either caused by problems on the server (i.e. servers which croak on SSLv23 or TLSv12 instead of replying with the proper version) or by some man in the middle which attempts to downgrade the protocol by disrupting handshakes with a higher protocol version. This has nothing to do with the normal handshake process but is only their to detect abnormal handshakes.